# Why do I have two different DNS suffix lists?

Tags: windows-xp, dns

My Windows XP laptop has two different DNS suffix lists.

The first is the one I see by selecting the Properties dialog of any of my network connections, selecting Internet Protocol > Properties > Advanced > DNS tab, and looking at the list under the "Append these DNS suffixes (in order)" option.

The second list is the one shown under "DNS Suffix Search List" when I run `ipconfig /all`.

As far as I can tell, only the second list ever gets used to resolve unqualified host names.

Why are there two different lists? How do I configure the second list? Or how can I make my computer use the first list?

Answer (score 0):

Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754143%28WS.10%29.aspx

"Append these DNS suffixes (in order), lists the DNS suffixes to search in the order listed when you use the Append these DNS suffixes option.

DNS suffix for this connection provides a space for you to specify a DNS suffix for this connection. If a DHCP server configures this connection and you do not specify a DNS suffix, a DNS suffix for this connection is assigned to this connection by the appropriately configured DHCP server. If you specify a DNS suffix, the DNS suffix assigned by the DHCP server is ignored. The local setting is used only if the associated Group Policy is disabled or unspecified."

Note that your DHCP server sends you some DNS suffixes, which are n you case the ones you can see with ipconfig /all